# Case sensitive to_s and to_i methods for 0-9, a-z, A-Z?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to do a simple obfuscation/shortener for IDs in my app.  For this, I'd like to map integers to strings and vice versa.

I can interchange easily with `to_i` and `to_s` like so:

```
>> 635.to_s(36)
# => "hn"
>> "hn".to_i(36)
# => 635
```

This takes into account 0-9 and a-z, but I would also like to take into account A-Z (capitalized), which would be functionally equivalent to `to_s(62)`.

Is there an easy way to do this in Ruby and/or Rails?

**EDIT**

I'd like to do this with 0-9, a-z, and A-Z if possible. The strings need to be url-friendly, and I'm using other characters like `-` to separate values in the url, so would be best to avoid those.

Comment: This would likely be something that isn't done "in" Ruby on Rails as much as something you would simply do with Ruby itself.  Nothing web framework about this problem at all.

Comment: I think base 64 is more popular because it is a flat number in the context of programming (2^6), and there is [a built-in library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a gem called base62 that does exactly what I described:

https://github.com/jtzemp/base62

```
require 'base62'

>> 635.base62_encode
=> "AF"
>> "AF".base62_decode
=> 635
```

I also made it rails-specific with a module that can be mixed into whatever models need the obfuscation / shortening:

```
module AdditionalMethods

  module Shortener
    def short_id
      self.id.base62_encode
    end
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end
    module ClassMethods
      def original_id(string)
        string.base62_decode
      end
      def find_by_short_id(string)
        self.find_by_id(self.original_id(string))
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AdditionalMethods::Shortener
  ...
end
```

Then

```
>> @post.id
=> 52
>> @post.short_id
=> "q"
>> Post.original_id("q")
=> 52
>> Post.find_by_short_id("q")
=> #<Post id: 52 ... >
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use base 58. There's a gem for that: http://rubygems.org/gems/base58

```
require 'base58'

Base58.encode(12345) # => 4ER
Base58.decode('4ER') # => 12345
```

As pointed out in the comments, this will leave out potentially ambivalent characters such as `I`, `l`, `0` and `O`.

Comment: This takes into account that most fonts have 0 and O looking identical as well as 'l' and 1 and 'I' looking identical.  So it may work for OP, but unsure if it is an exact match.  However, the nice thing about providing the gem location is that he can easily modify it to accommodate the missing characters.  +1 for that.

Comment: That misses `0`, `l`, `I`, `O`. The OP meant base 62, not base 58.

Comment: Yeah, what @sawa said. :)

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for. I'll wait a bit to see if the full spec shows up.

Comment: Sorry guys I better catch some sleep... Edited my answer accordingly in order to prevent confusion of future visitors.